# R package dependency hell. How to break out of it?

Tags: r, package

An trying to install the package 'gsbufn' from CRAN to solve a dependency, but it depends on 'proto' which cannot be found during installation:

```
* installing *source* package ‘gsubfn’ ...
** package ‘gsubfn’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘gsubfn’
    finding HTML links ... done
    as.function.formula                     html
    fn                                      html
    gsubfn-package                          html
    gsubfn                                  html
    match.funfn                             html
    read.pattern                            html
    strapply                                html
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : package ‘proto’ required by ‘gsubfn’ could not be found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/gsubfn’
```

However, 'proto' is installed and loads fine using library() and/or require(). My .libPaths() are correct, consistent and I can see the proto files on the filesystem.

Anyone know why 'gsubfn' is steadfastly refusing to acknowledge the existence of 'proto' and how to force it to behave, please?

This is for R 3.3.3.

```
> library('proto')
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.utf8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] proto_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3 tcltk_3.3.3
> .libPaths()
[1] "/cluster/gjb_lab/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3"
[2] "/cluster/gjb_lab/software/centos6.3/opt/R/3.3.3/lib64/R/library"
[3] "/usr/lib64/R/library"
```

Comment: What version of `proto` is required by the version of `gsubfn` you're trying to install?  What version of `proto` do you have?

Comment: @Mark I have `proto` v1.0.0 and the `DESCRIPTION` file for `gsubfn` makes no mention of version requirement.

Comment: out of curiosity what are you trying to use `gsubfn` for? The new [glue](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue) package is also helpful for string creation.

Comment: But this is really hard to debug with the info given. I guess making looking at `sessionInfo()` after loading `proto` by hand. And verifying what the `installed.packages()` looks like and the `.libPaths()` values are.

Comment: @MrFlick it's a dependency for the `rtf` package. It's only a suggestion and the code does run, but it's annoying that I can't fix this!

Comment: I've added `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()`, but can't add `installed.packages()` as it's too long.